# Sort Array 1 by ID of Array 2. While removing and adding elements from Array 1 depending on Array 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays. Each filled with unique identification numbers. I want to take the first Array

```
array1 = [ 
    {"name":"sos", "id":112},
    {"name":"apa", "id":671},
    {"name":"dos", "id":003},
]
```

And have its order match the order of array2 depending on each ones ID value. So that every id of array1 equals array2 and vice versa. In other words array1[x].id == array2[x].id for every value of x less than or equal to the length of the array.

```
array2 = [ 
    {"name":"sqe", "id":671},
    {"name":"pep", "id":003},
    {"name":"try", "id":163},
]
```

I also want to remove any element within array1 that does not have a corresponding id within array2. And add any element into array1 that has an id value that is not in array1 but is in array2, while again sorting it depending on its ID number.
Array1 must preserve its names that are associated with each id value, but when a new element is added its name can be set to the name of the id it is correlated with in array2.

I cant seem to wrap my mind on how to achieve this without running into special cases where it could mess up my order.

Comment: Your notation is not syntactically correct, but it's pretty clear what you mean.

Comment: Step 1: create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from `array1` mapping ids to objects.

Comment: Also your `array2` does not include all the id values from array 1.

Answer (score 0):

Build an array from `array2` that gives the index for each id value:

```
var indexes = array2.reduce(function(map, entry, index) {
  map[entry.id] = index;
  return map;
}, {});
```

Now you can create a new array from `array1`:

```
var newArray1 = array1.reduce(function(a, entry) {
  a[indexes[entry.id]] = entry;
  return a;
}, []);
```

Now, in your example data, your `array2` does not include all the id values that are present in `array1`.  It's not clear from your question what should be done in such cases.

One approach would be to create a lookup table from all the id values in `array2`, and then add to it the missing id values from `array1` with some larger index values.

Comment: Ill give a more through response when I am able to dive deeper into your solution, I appreciate the help. If I understand you correctly though, I do clarify in my question what should be done when array2 does not include an id value from array 1? In my question it says "remove any element within array1 that does not have a corresponding id within array2".

Answer (score 0):

- It'll order array2 like array1:
- It'll delete items of array2 if doesn't exist in array 1

```js
array1 = [ {"name":"sos", "id":112},{"name":"apa", "id":671},{"name":"dos", "id":003}]
array2 = [ {"name":"sqe", "id":671},{"name":"pep", "id":003},{"name":"try", "id":163}]

array2 = array2.filter((item2, i) => {
   let match = false;
   array1.forEach((item1, j) => {
       if(item1.id == item2.id) return match = true;
   })
   return  match
})

console.log(array1)
console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a map from your `array1`:

```
let map1 = new Map(array1.map(e => [e.id, e]))
```

Then iterate over your `array2` and map each item to its corresponding item in `array1`.

```
let newArray1 = array2.map(e => map1.get(e.id));
```